# Update multiple fields from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

The current query is:

```
update topics set posts = (select count(*) from posts where tid = 27), lastpost = (select max(pid) from posts where tid = 27) where tid = 27;
```

How do I merge the two sub-queries into this for the update query?

```
select count(*), select max(pid) from posts where tid = 27)
```

I could execute this as two separate queries obviously (read values from posts, write values to topics) but I'd like to do it in a single query if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `inner join` within the update statement :

```
update topics t
  join (
        select tid, count(*) as cnt, max(pid) as mx
          from posts
         group by tid
       ) p on p.tid = t.tid 
   set posts = p.cnt, lastpost = p.mx
 where t.tid = 27;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f0a500de22f2b7ab108fdf69cb760746)</kbd>

**As a side note :** *In this case not needed but starting from DB version 10.2 window analytic functions might also be used along with aggregation functions.*